# Using gruntjs, how do watch for changes in .coffee files?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs

I am new to gruntjs and here is my simple gruntfile:

```
/* global module:false */
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
      tasks: 'coffee'
    },
    coffee: {
      compile: {
        files: {
          'js/javascript/*.js': ['js/coffeescript/*.coffee'] // 1:1 compile
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-coffee');

  // Default task.
  grunt.registerTask('default', 'coffee');
};
```

When I run grunt it compiles fine. However, when I run grunt watch, it's just waiting and not detecting my changes.

Comment: Have you tried to define "... tasks: 'coffee -w' ... "?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should add files to watch:

```
watch: {
  coffee: {
    files: ['js/coffeescript/*.coffee'],
    tasks: 'coffee'
  }
}
```

From [example](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-commonjs-sample/blob/master/grunt.js)

Comment: That worked. Thank you. One more question, what is the syntax for preserving the folder structure of the coffee folder in the compiled js folder without having to list all of the coffeescript folders of your app?

Comment: It can be done with the unstable alpha version of Grunt, v0.4a but it is still being discussed. Check out this thread: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee/pull/1