# Grunt: Watch multiple files, Compile only Changed

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, gruntjs

I'm new to Grunt, and so far I'm enjoying it very much. 
I want Grunt to compile only the changed files when running `grunt watch`

In my Grunfile.coffee I currently have (relevant parts).
*Note: assets/javascript/app.coffee and assets/javascript/app.js are directories*

```
    coffee:
        default:
            expand: true
            cwd: "assets/javascript/app.coffee"
            src: ["*.coffee"]
            dest: "assets/javascript/app.js"
            ext: ".js"

    uglify:
        dev:
            options:
                beautify: true
                compress: false
                mangle: false
                preserveComments: 'all'

            files: 
                "js/app.js": "assets/javascript/app.js/*.js"
                "js/libs.js": "assets/javascript/libs/*.js"

    watch:
        coffeescript:
            files: 'assets/javascript/**/*.coffee'
            tasks: ["coffee"]

        javascript:
            files: "assets/**/*.js"
            tasks: ["uglify:dev"]
        livereload:
            files: ["Gruntfile.coffee", "js/*.js", "*.php", "css/*.css", "images/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}", "js/*.js", ]
            options:
                livereload: true
```

There is probably a shorter way around, but I'm compiling app.coffee to app.js first, so that after I distribute my work, people who aren't comfortable with Coffeescript can browse the code in somewhat reasonable manner.

The problem with all this is that now that I save a Coffeescript file, I get too many steps ( I think ):

```
>> File "assets/javascript/app.coffee/browse.coffee" changed.

Running "coffee:default" (coffee) task
File assets/javascript/app.js/browse.js created.
File assets/javascript/app.js/filters.js created.

Done, without errors.
Completed in 0.837s at Tue May 28 2013 12:30:18 GMT+0300 (EEST) - Waiting...
OK
>> File "assets/javascript/app.js/browse.js" changed.
>> File "assets/javascript/app.js/filters.js" changed.

Running "uglify:dev" (uglify) task
File "js/app.js" created.
File "js/libs.js" created.

Done, without errors.
Completed in 0.831s at Tue May 28 2013 12:30:19 GMT+0300 (EEST) - Waiting...
OK
>> File "js/app.js" changed.
>> File "js/libs.js" changed.

Completed in 0.000s at Tue May 28 2013 12:30:19 GMT+0300 (EEST) - Waiting...
```

Currently I'm just setting up my project, but I will have a lot more Coffeescript files, and I don't want Coffeescript to recompile all of the files, on each file change.

Furthermore, libs.js has no part in all of this at all, but I guess it is still compiled, because it also matches the "assets/**/*.js" pattern.

Is there a way to make Grunt compile only the files that have changed ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you watch multiple files, but only run task on changed file, in Grunt.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063266/how-do-you-watch-multiple-files-but-only-run-task-on-changed-file-in-grunt-js)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

**I've finally found a real solution!** And it's super simple too!

`npm install grunt-newer --save-dev`

Then in your Gruntfile (after loading the task in grunt):

```
watch:
    coffeescript:
        files: 'assets/javascript/**/*.coffee'
        tasks: ["newer:coffee"]
```

And that's it! [The Awesome **grunt-newer** is awesome!](https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-newer)

Comment: Nice -- that's exactly what I needed! I didn't even need to read any docs or instructions -- it just works.

Comment: grunt-newer has it's problems. For example it cannot be used with grunt-contrib-copy. Here is the discussion https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-newer/issues/39

Comment: `"... that's exactly what I needed! I didn't even need to read any docs or instructions ..."` An experienced developer would remark, that - even though it directly works without extra configuration - it has a great documentation. *scnr*

Answer (score 2):

If you concat all .coffee sources into one .js file, then you will have to recompile it every time if any of your sources changes. Split it up to several .js files and make a *release* task where you only concat these .js files. This way you still only need to include one .js file.

See [Using gruntjs, how do watch for changes in .coffee files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813514/using-gruntjs-how-do-watch-for-changes-in-coffee-files)

Comment: See that's the thing. I compile each Coffeescript file to a separate JavaScript file, so the compiler shouldn't actually touch the other coffeescript file. The Javascript files then are concatenated into app.js, but that's a separate task, that also accidentally invokes compressing of libs.js, which is also unnecessary.

Comment: Then just simply exclude lib.js from watch with "!js/libs.js". Maybe you can write your own [Custom filter](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#custom-filter-function) or ask for a [similar feature](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/pull/56).

Comment: This was actually the most sensible solution, sticking to it until I find something even better...

Answer (score 1):

The `grunt.event.on` event detects changes in files, receiving an `action` and `filepath` parameter.

Here's an untested example based on one of my gruntfiles. In this case, all my source coffeescript files are kept in a directory called sources, and for previewing they are compiled and saved to an identical directory structure under a directory called dev

```
SOURCES_DIR = 'sources'
DEV_DIR = 'dev'

grunt.initConfig
  watch :
    all :
      files : ["**/*.coffee"]
  coffee :
    dev :
      files :
        dest : "app.js"
grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-watch'
grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-coffee'

grunt.registerTask 'build', ['coffee:dev']

grunt.event.on('watch', (action,filepath) ->
  # Determine the full directory of the changed file
  wdi = filepath.lastIndexOf '/'
  wd =  filepath.substring 0,wdi

  # remove `sources` prefix from that directory
  fpath = wd.replace(SOURCES_DIR,'') + '/'

  # determine the filename
  fnamei = filepath.lastIndexOf '.'
  fname = filepath.substring wdi+1,fnamei # NOTE: this breaks the case where in same dir

  # concatenate fpath and fname with the dir to be compiled into
  deststr = "#{DEV_DIR}#{fpath}#{fname}.coffee"


  # set coffee.dev.files value in the coffee task to have am entry of form {"destination":"source"}
  obj = {}
  obj[deststr] = filepath
  grunt.config "coffee.dev.files", obj

  # fire the coffee task
  grunt.task.run "coffee"
)
```

Hope that helps.

**EDIT:** Probably not exactly what you want - because no doubt you want access to intermediary variables, actions and so forth - but you could use grunt to just run a shell coffee command. The `grunt-shell` npm task does this, for example

**EDIT2:** I've faced continued problems with `grunt.watch.on` not working consistently in grunt 0.4.1 on OSX 10.8 and MacVim 7.3; for whatever reason, it stops watching. I've reverted back to just using the basic grunt initConfig object but with much more granularity so it only watches and compiles relatively small groups of files rather than the whole lot. This slows down the build time considerably, but it much more robust. Your mileage may very.

Comment: Thanks, this actually looks like something I was looking for. I'll take a closer look at it later.

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled upon this, too and did not find any working versions that worked with the current version (0.4.1) But Jof Arnolds answer showed a good approach.

This is what I came up with:

```
# only recompile changed files
grunt.event.on "watch", (action, filepath) ->
  # note that we have to manually change the target file name to 
  # our desired format
  targetName = filepath.replace(/\/(client|shared)/, "")
    .replace(".coffee", ".js")
    .replace("app/", "")

  options =
    src: filepath
    dest: "public/javascripts/#{targetName}"

  grunt.config ["coffee", "client"], options
```

I have a coffee section that looks somewhat like this:

```
coffee:
  client:
    options:
      sourceMap: false
    files: [
      expand: true
      cwd: "app"
      src: ["*/client/**/*.coffee", "helpers/{client,shared}/*.coffee"]
      dest: "public/javascripts"
      rename: (folder, name) ->
        name = name.replace(/\/(client|shared)/, "")

        [folder, name].join path.sep
      ext: ".js"
    ]
```