# How to automate javascript version increment if file changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I'm using `grunt` to build a `javascript/angularjs` project in the following order:

`clean copy > uglify > cssmin`.

Now if I change a `js` file I'd always have to manually add a version increment at the end of the script tag, so that the browser can detect the changes.

```
<script src="/js/myscript?v123"></script>
```

Question: how can I automate this process using `grunt`? If I run the "grunt" command, only files that changed compared to the last run should get a version increment. So that the browser can reuse the cached files as much as possible.

Comment: Are you using a server-side language, or is it plain html?

Comment: I'm using `angularjs`, thus `javascript, css, html`.

Comment: I'd appreciate an anwer to my quesiton more than a good wish, but thanks ;)

Comment: how big is your app(html, js, css) without libraries? If it is ~ 1Mb or less, I would advise to simply concat your app into single app.js and use cacheBust.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-assets-versioning

Comment: It's <1mb but I'd like to have different parts of the application being compiled into different minified js scripts (I will mostly change only parts of the app, and only the minified version affected should get recompiled with a new version).

Comment: @cesarluis `assets-versioning` seems to *always* perform a version increment on compile. I only want to increment the version for files that actually *changed*.

Answer (score 2):

I know short answers are not OK (not enough rep to comment), but you might want to checkout [grunt-asset-cachebuster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-asset-cachebuster). I haven't tried it myself but there are plenty of examples in their npm page.

Also checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19722900/2620998) about [grunt-newer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-newer)

Comment: The plugin adds the timestamp to every file on compilation. I only want to add it on files that changed comparing to the last compilation. Apart from that it looks promising.

Comment: I have found a similar question. Checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19722900/2620998